# What is the @FindBy equivalent of By.CssSelector?

Tags: java, selenium

Using Inspect Element on Firefox, and Copy CSS Selector, I get the following:

```
div.GBNJJH1BCUB:nth-child(3) > input:nth-child(1)
```

I have declared that in my page class thus:

```
private static final String logoutButtonCss="div.GBNJJH1BBUB:nth-child(3) > input:nth-child(1)";
```

Is this the correct way to find this element?

```
@FindBy(css=logoutButtonCss) private WebElement logoutButton;
```

The byExpression allows me to use Css Selector:

```
By byExpression = By.cssSelector(logoutButtonCss);
```

I am using the latter here:

```
public static boolean isWebElementPresent(By byExpression, WebDriver driver) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Constant.timeOut);
    try { 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byExpression));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Common.class.getName());
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.warning("Timeout searching for " + byExpression);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you consider to read the docs for once atleast? http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html

Comment: @DebanjanB If the answer was in the document I would not have asked the question.

Comment: Just try it... did it work? What's the problem?

Answer (score -2):

The @FindBy annotation requires literal text, not variables:

```
@FindBy(css="div.GBNJJH1BBUB:nth-child(3) > input:nth-child(1)") 
private WebElement logoutButton;
```

Comment: Bill Hileman - that statement is simply not true. FindBy works perfectly well with variables, provided they are defined as static final.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem you are encountering?  I've read and re-read your post and all I see is "is this correct?"  Does it work?  If it does, then it's correct.  I incorrectly assumed it didn't, and offered a suggestion.

Comment: Are you perhaps not initializing the POM with the pagefactory?

Comment: Bill Hileman - my question is as stated in the title: What is the FindBy equivalent of By.CssSelector? I am looking for the correct syntax as I cannot find it in the documentation. All my Page Objects are initialised using PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);